# Win 7 Favorites -> Win 10 Quick Access, also changed Shortcuts -> Actual Folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, favorites

Under Win 7, the Favorites list is a collection of shortcuts to folders.
As such, each of these shortcuts has its own name and target (one can see this by right clicking on one of these). They do not need to coincide. One can change the name that shows up in Favorites, it does not change the name of the folder pointed at.

Under Win 10, the Quick Access list (replacement of Favorites) is a collection of folders (again, one can see this by right clicking on one of these). I do not know details on the way it is handled.
As such, whenever I rename one of the items under Quick Access, I am actually renaming the folder it points to.
I would like to change this behavior.

**Is this possible at all?**

Comment: During the development of Windows 10, one of the highly voted requests was: Every time I rename a folder, I have to rename its Favorites's shortcut. I wish it would get renamed automatically. Well, now there it is. Enjoy.

Comment: @FleetCommand - Unfortunate (for me). Perhaps there was a setting that one can use to select the behavior... or else.